# Existing file not found

Tags: linux, bash

There is a bash script that I use to extract the artwork from MP3 files before converting them.

```
#!/bin/bash

MUSIC_FILE=$1
IMAGE_FILE=""
TIMESTAMP=$2

if [ -z "$MUSIC_FILE" ] ; then
  exit 2;
fi

if [ -z $TIMESTAMP ] ; then
  TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s)
fi 

IMAGE_FILE=`/usr/bin/eyeD3 --write-images=. "$MUSIC_FILE" 2>&1 | grep Writing  | sed -e 's/Writing //g' -e 's/\.\.\.//g' | tr ' ' '_'`

if [ -z $IMAGE_FILE ] ; then
  exit 3
fi

if [ -e $IMAGE_FILE ] ; then
  /usr/bin/convert $IMAGE_FILE $TIMESTAMP.png
  exit 0
else 
  exit 4
fi
```

The artwork file is well extracted, I can see it by a ls output, and the variable used to get the file name is correct (no heading/trailing spaces, etc), but within the script nor convert nor any additional ls finds it (no such file or directory)...

It really drives me nut...

Additional information : when I launch the script with the -x flag, every representation of my file name is yellow-colorized, can't figure out why...

Thanks for your help !

Jérémie

Comment: Does `$IMAGE_FILE` contain spaces?

Comment: -z and -n refer to strings, not files. You probably need -f and/or -r and/or -e and/or -s

Comment: Actually, `[ -z $IMAGE_FILE ]` will evaluate to true if IMAGE_FILE is blank (because then you're running the command `[ -z ]`, and with a single argument `[` just checks whether that argument is blank, and "-z" is not). As in many other cases, the correct answer is to wrap variables in double-quotes when you expand them: `[ -z "$IMAGE_FILE" ]`

Comment: I have to verify that the string exists, because if the MP3 has not any image embedded, the script will have to bypass the convert command, and embed a default image instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to obtain filename by filtering command's output, why did you not:

```
#!/bin/bash

MUSIC_FILE="$1"
[ -f "$MUSIC_FILE" ] || exit 2

TIMESTAMP=${2:-$(date +%s)}

mydir=$(mktemp -d)
/usr/bin/eyeD3 --write-images=$mydir "$MUSIC_FILE" >/dev/null 2>&1
filename=($(/bin/ls -1 $mydir))

[ -f "$mydir/$filename" ] &&
    convert $mydir/$filename" $TIMESTAMP.png

rm -fR $mydir
```

Not tested, but could work... ( approx ;-)

Comment: Perfect ! I just had to rewrite `filename=($(/bin/ls -1 $mydir))` to `filename=$(/bin/ls -1 mydir`. Thanks a lot !